# Symfony Formular

Tags: php, symfony

I made my first steps in Symfony 3.x.
I tried to make a simple small form, but I am getting an error message which I don't understand.

> Variable "read_only" does not exist in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 323

My PHP:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class StartController extends Controller            
{  
    public function testMeAction(){
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('task',TextType::class)
                        ->getForm();

        return $this->render('psychoform.html.twig',array(
             'form'=>$form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

My Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>  
 <body>                        
{{ form_start(form) }}     
{{ form_end(form) }}
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help. -Micha

Comment: Where do you get that error message, is it from the console? If so, what command were you running? The message is pointing to the file "form_div_layout.html.twig".

Comment: You have composer.json issues.  read_only was removed in S3.0.  Looks like you have a older version of twig.  Start over completely and make sure you download the latest project.

Comment: i get the error it in the browser

Comment: The Error is gone after updating Symfony and twig....Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

"read_only" has been deprecated in Symfony 2.8, and instead should use read only as an attribute.

[Symfony Github Issue Link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10658)

The issue must have occurred because of old symfony or twig version. Try updating both.